# In a dplyr pipeline, programmatically rename a column (both left and right-hand-side)

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to programmatically rename a column (using one passed variable) in a dplyr pipeline. I set up a minimal example below with comments. The final couple attempts work. But they feel odd. Is this really the best-practices way to achieve my result in the tidyverse? If not, what is?  Also, why does `!!` evaluate on the left-hand-side but not `str_c()`?

I still feel like I'm not grokking how to *think* in tidyverse---especially when it comes to these `:=`, `!!!`, `!!`, `~`, `vars()`, `funs()`, `enquo()`, etc., operators and functions.

```
library(tidyverse) 

OLD_COL_NAME <- "disp"
NEW_COL_NAME <- "PREFIX_disp"

# Gives desired result, but would prefer not to pass `NEW_COL_NAME`
mtcars %>%
  rename(!!NEW_COL_NAME := !!OLD_COL_NAME)
# mpg cyl PREFIX_disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4           21.0   6       160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6       160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

# Thought this would give BOTH desired result and functionality. 
# Surprisingly to me, didn't work. 
mtcars %>%
  rename(str_c("PREFIX_", !!OLD_COL_NAME) := !!OLD_COL_NAME)
# Error: The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol

# Also surprinsigly, this didn't work either
mtcars %>%
  rename(!!str_c("PREFIX_", !!OLD_COL_NAME) := !!OLD_COL_NAME)
# Error in !OLD_COL_NAME : invalid argument type

# Gives desired result. But clunky. Is this really the best-practices approach 
# in the tidyverse?
mtcars %>%
  rename_at(vars(!!OLD_COL_NAME), funs(str_c("PREFIX_", !!OLD_COL_NAME)))

# Gives desired result. Less clunky. Again, is this the best-practices approach?
mtcars %>%
  rename_at(vars(!!OLD_COL_NAME), ~ str_c("PREFIX_", .x))
```

Comment: As you said `str_c()` has to be evaluated as well, to do so simply move `!!` before it and everything should work as intended: `mtcars %>% rename(!!str_c("PREFIX_", OLD_COL_NAME) := !!OLD_COL_NAME)`

Comment: Hah! That's it! I I had tried `mtcars %>% rename(!!str_c("PREFIX_", !!OLD_COL_NAME) := !!OLD_COL_NAME)` previously, which threw an error. So the idea here is that `!!` will evaluate the function it's tied to **and** all variables passed to it. Am I saying that right?

Comment: I would rename them this way: `mtcars %>% 
  purrr::set_names(~ stringr::str_c("PREFIX_",.))`

Answer (score 1):

We can now do:

```
mtcars %>% 
  rename("PREFIX_{ OLD_COL_NAME }" := !! OLD_COL_NAME)
```

See the announcement about [glue strings in result names](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/glue-strings-and-tidy-eval/#custom-result-names)