# Using glue in new column name in rename() in R

Tags: r

I have a date variable, that can be set at the beginning of my script. Later in the script this date variable is used as part of a new column name using glue.

```
df <- df %>%
  rename("Date" = glue("{date_variable}"),
         glue("Change since {date_variable}") = change)
```

This is what setting the date variable looks like:

```
date_variable <- "2020-04-15"
```

Now the first rename, where the glue is in the old column name, works perfectly. The second part, where the glue is in the new column name, does not. It returns:

> Unexpected) '=' in:
> "df <- df %>%
> rename(glue("Test {date_variable}") ="

Is it simply not possible to use a glue command in a new variable name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a dplyr pipeline, programmatically rename a column (both left and right-hand-side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063993/in-a-dplyr-pipeline-programmatically-rename-a-column-both-left-and-right-hand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is also possible, without explicit use of `glue`, but with the walrus operator `:=`, like in [@Ronak Shah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67213452/6197649):

```
df %>% rename("Change since {date_variable}" := change)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `glue` with `rename` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

df %>% rename("Date" = glue("{date_variable}"), 
              !!glue("Change since {date_variable}") := change)

#  Date Change since 2020-04-15
#1    1                       2
#2    2                       3
#3    3                       4
#4    4                       5
```

Another option is to use `rename_with` which will not require `glue`.

```
df %>% 
  rename_with(~c('Date', paste('Change since', date_variable)), 
               c(date_variable, 'change'))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame("2020-04-15" = 1:4, change = 2:5, check.names = FALSE)
date_variable <- "2020-04-15"
```

Comment: Thank you! What exactly does using `:=` instead of `=`do?

Comment: When LHS of `mutate` is supposed to be used as a variable we use `:=` along with `!!`. You can read more about it in `Forcing Names` part at https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html